# How do I split and separate plus operators which is contained inside the string

Tags: java, string, split

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "I+Love";
    s.split("+");
}
```

this is throwing Exception in thread "main" `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException`:

Answer (score 6):

You need to escape the `+` special character:

```
s.split("\\+");  // split accepts a regular expression and `+` is a metacharacter
```

Comment: @manouti Could you tell me the reason why we can not split directly without using backslashes?  This happening not only for the "+" symbol its happening '*' '.' etc...

Comment: @DharshanSithamparam Because these are special characters that have their own meaning in regular expressions. For example, `.` denotes a special character that means any character.